# mysql left join with nulls in php

Tags: php, mysql, join, null

Example scenario; lets say I'm searching for employees and their employers

```
tblEmployee
eid | name
1  | james
2  | harry

tblCompany
cid | name
1  | ABC Ltd
2  | XYZ Corp

tblMappings
mid | eid | cid
1  | 1   | 2
```

James is assigned to the company XYZ Corp, but harry has no assignment. I want to pull out all employees whether they are assigned or not;

```
SELECT * FROM `tblEmployee`
LEFT JOIN `tblMappings` ON 
`tblEmployee`.`eid` = `tblMappings`.`eid`
```

This returns the following in phpMyAdmin;

```
eid | name  | mid  | eid  | cid
1   | james | 1    | 1    | 2
2   | harry | NULL | NULL | NULL
```

I'm performing the query in PHP and using:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) { ...blah.... }
```

But for harry $row['eid'] is blank. I'm not sure how to work this one out so any points would be greatly apprecited. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `eid` field from `tblEmployee` isn't empty, but the `eid` field from `tblMappings` is empty, which is expected since there's no matching record in that table. Specify which fields you want instead of `SELECT * ...`.

```
SELECT e.*, m.mid, m.cid FROM `tblEmployee` e
LEFT JOIN `tblMappings` m ON 
e.`eid` = m.`eid`
```

Comment: I used SELECT * because there are more employee fields like last name and address etc, and I do actually want them all, but this is new syntax you have provided me with, something to go and read about which has fixed my problem. Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT tblEmployee.* FROM `tblEmployee`
LEFT JOIN `tblMappings` ON `tblEmployee`.`eid` = `tblMappings`.`eid`
```

Both `tblEmployee` and `tblMappings` also contains column `eid`,
and naturally the second eid from `tblMappings` is override the first one.

To solve this, you can specify the table name in the return columns

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using `SELECT *`. It's a bad habit.

Instead, consider this:

```
SELECT `tblEmployee`.`eid` FROM `tblEmployee`
LEFT JOIN `tblMappings` ON 
`tblEmployee`.`eid` = `tblMappings`.`eid`
```